# Cloudflare retain original IP address with Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ip-address, cloudflare

Cloudflare provides a number of solutions to retain the original client's IP address, but mostly it is for people who own access to the physical box or have IaaS.

For Google app engine, how can I make it work with Cloudflare such that I still can extract the original client's IP address?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR to get the "real" IP. It appears you can get at that in Java using these details:

```
 String ipaddress = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");

 if (ipaddress  == null)
        ipaddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Source = http://thepcspy.com/read/getting_the_real_ip_of_your_users/

Related and might be helpful: http://www.coderanch.com/t/293684/JSP/java/client-IP-address-Domain-Java

Answer (score 2):

According to [cloudflare support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786-Why-do-my-server-logs-show-CloudFlare-s-IPs-using-CloudFlare-) they are setting a header: `CF-Connecting-IP`.

To retrieve this header in java you can use

```
String paramIpAddress = request.getHeader("CF-Connecting-IP");
if (paramIpAddress == null) {
    paramIpAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Comment: This even works for Google Cloud Armor header based rules. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following server variables:

$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] Real visitor IP address

$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"] Country of visitor

$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_VISITOR"] If its HTTP or HTTPS

Below is the sample codes in PHP:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, google app engine only runs java or python. i'm running java - do you know how should it look like in java? thanks